# UIView convertRect: - finding subview position two views deep

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, cgrect

In the pictures below, each rectangle is a UIView. View A has a weak reference to view C. View A creates view D and needs to add it as a subview to view C so that view A is covered completely. I therefore need to get the position of view A relative to view C. Adding view D as a subView of view A at {0,0} is not an option for this particular case - it has to be a subview of C.

*View hierarchy starting point*
[image: View hierarchy starting point]

*View hierarchy goal point*
[image: View hierarchy goal point]

I've tried every combination of `convertRect:toView:` and `convertRect:fromView:` I can think of, passing in combinations of the three views as sender and receiver as well as using their subviews, but there are too many combinations and I just can't understand how it works. I would be really grateful if somebody could post the correct syntax firstly so I can get it working and more importantly so I can work through a working example to understand what the function is actually doing.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`convertRect:` is the right way to go :

```
let viewD = UIView()
viewD.frame = viewA.viewC.convertRect(viewA.frame, fromView: viewA.superview!)
viewA.viewC.addSubview(viewD)
```

In Objective-C:

```
UIView *viewD = [[UIView alloc] init];
viewD.frame = [viewA.viewC convertRect:viewA.frame fromView:viewA.superview];
[viewA.viewC addSubview:viewD];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I don't quite understand the syntax of this in Swift... Do you know the Objective C equivalent? Edit - would it be `viewD.frame = [self.viewC convertRect:self.frame fromView:self.superview];` (called from an instance method on viewA)

Comment: aha! Turns out I'm an idiot! Your swift example worked perfectly when converted to Objective C as per my comment above, but didn't appear to work first because I was doing the conversion before I had added ViewA to ViewB, so its superview was nil and therefore returned CGRectZero as its frame during the conversion. I moved that line of code after the point at which ViewA gets added to the view hierarchy and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!